# Sending a file in multipart post request to a rest service from wso2

Tags: java, http-post, wso2, wso2-esb

I am fetching data from database and converting data into CSV file.That CSV file need to be send in multipart post request to rest service from WSO2 ESB.I searched a lot to implement the same through sequence.Please help me how can I do this.

```
POST /fileupload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 663e42c3-5652-32cb-7f81-94e525da157f
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

 ----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CustomerName"

 test
 ----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
 Content-Type: 


 ----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

I tried the java code to upload the same and later I will change it to mediator.

```
    String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
   String urlToConnect = "localhost:8080/fileupload";
   String boundary ="---"+ Long.toHexString( System.currentTimeMillis() ); // Just generate some unique random value
   HttpURLConnection connection = null;
   try
   {
       connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL( urlToConnect ).openConnection();
   }
   catch(MalformedURLException e1)
   {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch(IOException e1)
   {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }

   connection.setDoOutput(true); // This sets request method to POST.
   connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
   PrintWriter writer = null;
   try
   {
       writer = new PrintWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8" ),true);
       File uploadFile = new File("abc.csv");
       String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
       writer.append("--"+boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
       writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CustomerName\"").append(LINE_FEED).append(LINE_FEED);
       writer.append("SCLAqAHxvjcAAAFMzOIL7ghY").append(LINE_FEED);
       writer.append("--"+boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
       writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+fileName+"\"\r\nContent-Type: false").append(LINE_FEED).append(LINE_FEED).append(LINE_FEED);
       BufferedReader reader = null;
       try
       {

           reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(uploadFile ), "UTF-8" ) );
           for( String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; )
           {
               writer.append( line ).append(LINE_FEED);
           }

           writer.append("--"+boundary+"--");
           writer.append(LINE_FEED);
           writer.flush();
       }
       catch(IOException e)
       {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Please suggest me is it possible to send by built-in wso2 mediators.Otherwise I need to convert the above code into wso2 class mediator.